# How to return nullable datetime in ef linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is what I am trying to do.

```
data = (from t in db.Table
        where ...
        select new
        {
            Property = t.Table2.Any() ? new Nullable<DateTime>(t.Table2.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateField).FirstOrDefault().DateField) : null
        });
```

if there is anything in table2 i want to get the most recent date if not then return null but it's not letting me use new Nullable<>(). Also AS DateTime? does not work. This used to work in linq2sql but using EF which I have switched to it throws errors.

Comment: Is DateField a DateTime or a nullable DateTime?

Comment: Also, take a step back and explain what you want the query to do exactly. It may be you are attacking it the wrong way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = (from t in db.Table
    where ...
    select new
    {
        Property = t.Table2.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateField).select(x=> x.DateField).FirstOrDefault()
    });
```